# Binding to Attached Properties in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

How can I bind to an attached property in Xamarin Forms XAML?

This doesn't work but it compiles and makes the most sense:

```
BindingContext="{x:Binding Source={x:Reference ControlName}, Path=(XMLNameSpace:ClassName.AttachedPropertyName)}"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use an attached `BindableProperty` as binding source, as there is no property backing up that BP in the Control you reference as Source. I can't think of any way making this work directly with bindings.

What will work is going through a ViewModel of some sort (can be defined as a StaticResource), and bind `ControlName.AttachedProperty` to a property of that VM (using `OneWayToSource` mode) and then bind to that property of that temporary VM.

Comment: I created an issue to support this: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10004