# Xamarin Forms loop through list in a Grid

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem.
I created the following class:

```
public class OrderBundles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NumOfTrades { get; set; }
    public List<Trade> Trades { get; set; }
}

public class Trade
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Coin { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string ProfitUSDT { get; set; }
}
```

Now the bundles are working as follows: A bundle contains a SellOrder at first and then all Buy orders that are connected to a Sell.

Using that I want to create the following:
[image]

Now I already created a `CollectionView` with a `ViewModel` attached to it, but the problem then is, how can I loop inside the CollectionView row through the other list, so I can use the RowSpan?

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean to "loop inside the CollectionView, to use the RowSpan"?

Comment: As you can see I want a RowSpan on the SellProfit column, that needs to overlap all the buys below it. Now all the rows the ProfitUSDT has to overlap is inside the Trades list. That means that the `RowSpan of the ProfitUSDT = Trades.Count` If I only use a CollectionView I can't set the RowSpawn, because each row has its own grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry , i misunderstood your question , so actually your problem is equal to `is it possible to create bind on attached property(Grid.RowSpan)` ,  xamarin does not support the feature for now .

Refer

[Binding to Attached Properties in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42544575/binding-to-attached-properties-in-xamarin-forms)
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1647

#### Update

You could create a custom view as CollectionView.ItemTemplate , set `rowSpan` in method `BindingContextChanged` programatically .

```
   public CustomGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContextChanged += View1_BindingContextChanged;
    }

    private void View1_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OrderBundles obj = this.BindingContext;

        Grid.SetRowSpan(profitLabel, obj.Trades.Count);
    }
```

[image]

Sample link:https://github.com/ColeXm/GridSample

Comment: But I can have multiple sells, so multiple profit columns. This only works for 1 sell

Comment: So there is no way, to achieve what I want? No other View?

Comment: Can you show me what the full CustomView looks like? I mean, is the type a `ViewCell` or....?

Comment: Wait for my sample.

Comment: I've uploaded the sample on github , please check it .

Comment: There is only 1 bug with this.... If I create a much larger list and then scroll in it, it crashes after some new items have been shown or it crashes if I change the ListSource with a different list with different trades with the message: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the following line: `List<Trade> list = obj.Trades;`. How can I fix this?

Comment: could you post the code Which can reproduce the error？

Comment: It is your code in the View1.xaml.cs, but with more data!

Comment: I have a ViewModel bound to the CollectionView and if you change the source of the CollectionView it also crashes

Comment: Can you please look at this question about your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62242329/xamarin-forms-collectionview-doesnt-show-properly